# Extracting a set of values from a single integer

Tags: perl, bitwise-operators, subroutine

I have a number of things (let's call them nodes... it doesn't matter), conveniently referred to as node1, node2, ... nodeN.

The tricky part is that i need have a perl subroutine that takes an integer that refers to a set of nodes. My approach is this:

1. Each node is given a value based on powers of 2, like this:

   - node1 = 1
   - node2 = 2
   - node3 = 4
   - node4 = 8
   - ...
   - node8 = 128
   - etc
2. The value for each node is added up to produce an integer. For example, nodes 1, 3, 4 and 7 results in as integer of 77.

Now, how would I go about creating a subroutine that takes an integer like that and returns an array of node numbers?

---

PS:

- The maximum amount of nodes is configurable. 16 is a reasonable max.
- If I am approaching this an overly cumbersome way, I'm open to suggestions for a better way of producing a set of nodes from a single value.

Comment: surprised to see no answers using http://p3rl.org/vec or http://p3rl.org/unpack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set $max to the number of nodes (e.g. 16).

```
sub nodes {
    my $num = shift;
    return grep { $num & 2 ** $_ } 1 .. $max - 1;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Only thing is that this requires the first node to have a value of 2 instead of 1, but that's not an issue at all. Cheers!

Comment: You can change it to `($_ - 1)` to work from 1. Also noticed I changed 0 to 1 because 0 can never return 1 with `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 16 nodes:

```
sub nodes {
    my ($num) = @_;
    grep {($num >> ($_ - 1)) & 1} 1..16;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Const::Fast;

const my @NODE_SET => (0 .. 31);
const my @NODE_NAMES => map "node$_", @NODE_SET;
const my @POWERS_OF_2 => map 2**$_, @NODE_SET;

my @examples = (
    0b10011100111001011001110011100101,
    0b00010100101001111001110011100101,
    0b11110001010001101001110011100101,
);

print "@$_\n" for map extract_nodes($_), @examples;

sub extract_nodes {
    my $encoded_node = shift;
    return [ @NODE_NAMES[
        grep $POWERS_OF_2[$_] & $encoded_node, @NODE_SET
        ]
    ];
}
```